# Is Google's reCapture tool 508 compliant?

Tags: recaptcha, section508

I have a page that uses reCaptcha from another source, which has a few 508 compliance issues and I have to replace it.

I am thinking about using Google's reCapture tool

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Is it 508-compliant?

Answer (score 1):

According to a Terrill Thompson blog post - "[reCAPTCHA Accessibility reVISTED](http://terrillthompson.com/blog/682)," Google's reCAPTCHA is somewhat accessible, depending on whether or not the user is authenticated by just clicking the check box or if the reCAPTCHA tool requires them to complete the secondary CAPTCHA (if the Google algorithm determines that you are possibly not a human and requires an additional audio or visual test.) Overall, I don't think you can say this tool passes 508 compliance because the secondary captcha is inaccessible to deaf-blind users and keyboard users can't access the secondary visual challenge.